# Image Render Works, Animation Render Doesn't

Tags: rendering, animation, cycles-render-engine, texturing, eevee-render-engine

I've been working on a donut (BlenderGuru) and it's all been working great. I render a single frame with F12 and it renders fine. Once I go to Render -> Render Animation, it's just one of my textures?

Viewport:
[image]

Image Render (Frame 0):
[image]

Animation Render (Frame 0):
[image]

Yes I know it's Eevee engine, but it shows the same thing in Cycles. I did notice that the animation renders part of my plate texture, but with a pink tint. Any help is appreciated, I'm trying to get this finished by tomorrow (Valentine's Day!)

Answer (score 2):

It was a noob problem. I had my local camera set to my camera, but the actual scene camera was my donut's icing...? I think Blender also bugged out, because when I reopened the scene, the regular F12 still image render had the same result.

Anyways, how to fix it:
Go to Scene Properties > Scene > Camera, then you can use the eye dropper to pick the camera you want to use.

[image]